# WSL2 docker .NET container Failed to bind to address http://[::]:80: address already in use

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, wsl-2

There are a few similar questions for this issue but I don't think this exact one.

All of my local dev containers were running fine yesterday on their respective :80 and :443 ports. This was both starting them using docker-compose and also in debug mode from Visual Studio.

All of a sudden this morning I'm getting the following error:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://[::]:80: address already in use.

FYI, all of these exact same containers and config run at this moment on my other machine (i.e. laptop) so it is a machine specific issue.

I'm using WSL2 and the latest version of Docker Desktop (using the WSL2 engine).

I did do the latest Windows cumulative update yesterday but after doing that things were still running fine.

I've run the following command to see if anything is using port 80:

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

And there are no results (I assume this means nothing is running on the port).

I have run the following command to check that no other containers are running too:

```
docker ps
```

I've stopped and started and restarted again everything from docker to my whole machine.

My docker override file has the following ASP setting:

```
- ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
```

Unsurprisingly removing the http://+:80 solves my issue and my container starts up using its 443 port.

I'm at a complete loss as to what could be causing this and whilst I can happily just use the :443 ports it would be good to figure out what is going on and solve it.

Comment: We never know for sure, but I'm guessing they consider it off-topic.  I've tended not to vote-to-close or downvote on Docker questions, but is an issue with Docker/networking/ports/web-server *"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"*, even if you need it for a development task?  The problem is that it's not a ServerFault question and it would likely be closed on Super User since it's *too* programming focused (at least as written).  For that reason, I tend to give it a pass here, but others may not.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I saw a lot of similar questions so felt this was an appropriate one that could be solved via a docker config etc which I've known people to help with on here before. Will keep it up for now but if it really upsets people I'll happily remove the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue on Docker Desktop 4.13.0 and 4.18.0.
In my case the issue appeared due to automatic upgrade of WSL to version 1.2.0.

Checking [WSL Releases](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases), I could see that this release is now marked as pre-release, which makes me believe that it was once set as **latest** but later was demoted to **pre-release**.

Check your version of WSL:

```
wsl --version
```

I have fixed the issue after upgrading to the latest pre-release version of WSL using command:

```
wsl --update --pre-release
```

This will upgrade you to the latest pre-release version, however it is worth checking what stable version is currently available. Possibly the issue is fixed and new stable version is already released.

Comment: This solved it for me, something "magically" updated me to WSL 1.2 without me asking for it. Never used a pre-release WSL, never accepted anything, didn't install or update anything last few days, but something decided to update me to a broken WSL 1.2 preview version anyway.

Comment: Upgrading to pre-release version 1.2.5 from 1.2.0 has resolved the issue for me. Hopefully it doesn't come back. It would be nice if there was a way to upgrade to the latest stable version, but `wsl --update` doesn't appear to allow downgrading.

Comment: The latest release seems to have solved it for me too v1.2.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: disregard my answer, since the problem came back.

I ran into this problem and resolved it by upgrading to version 4.18.0 (104112) and then running "Reset to factory defaults". I'm not sure if simply upgrading would have fixed the bug or not, since I didn't try each step independently. Note that there's no mention of this bug being fixed in [the release notes for the new version](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/#4180).

Good luck!

Comment: I'm in the same spot... Everything has stopped working since a few days. Doing a factory reset works but then the problem reappears after a few days

Answer (score 0):

Local IIS on my host machine was using port 80 and I temporarily solved the problem (until the root cause of the issue gets fixed) by changing the default Web Site's port to 81 as below:

[image]

**Edit: Updating WSL version to the latest version (1.2.5 currently) fixed the issue for me. I updated it by opening WSL app's installation info from Microsoft Store and clicking on the "Update" button. It should be noted that Microsoft Store doesn't distinguish pre-release versions from the stable versions as of now so it will auto-update the applications to their pre-release versions and that was the cause of this bug actually. Updating the app from Microsoft Store will again update it to another pre-release version but I'll stick to Microsoft Store installation for a while hoping that they change this behavior..**